# ASP.NET query parameter part of string

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, parameters

I'm new to both Visual Studio and ASP.NET.

I have the following code in VS query builder:
`SELECT [Column1], [Column2], Column3 FROM [Table] WHERE (Column3 = ?)`

The problem is that this displays only results in which the WHERE clause is met for the whole field. I also need results where the parameter is just part of the field. Something similar is done in Access for a given value: `*value*`.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE (Column3 like '%' + ? + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already mentioned the word *parameter*, it's always better to use [`Sql-Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid [**sql-injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and conversion issues.

```
string sql = @"
             SELECT 
                [Column1], [Column2], Column3 
             FROM 
                [Table] 
             WHERE 
                (Column3 LIKE @searchPattern)";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchPattern", string.Format("%{0}%", str));
    con.Open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            string col1 = reader.GetString(0); // for example etc....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still too complicated for my begginer level but might give it a try later. Thank you. :)